# The significance of the composition of an operator and its adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, motivation

As I read the literature, I have noticed that the composition $T^*T$ of a linear operator $T:H\to H$ and its adjoint frequently turns up in all kind of places. I am aware that it is Hermitian (at least when $T$ is bounded), that $||Tx||^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle x,T^*Tx\rangle$ and other basic stuff like that. However, I don't quite "feel" what the notion $T^*T$ really is and why is it so ubiquitous.

I know that this might seem vague but can anyone give me a general idea of how I should view $T^*T$? What dose it do to a vector and what are its important properties?

I am particularly struck by the fact that $||A||_2^2=\rho(A^*A)$ when $A$ is a matrix representing a finite dimensional operator and that $I+T^*T$ is a bijection.

Comment: You wrote down the most important property: $\|T x\|^2 = \langle x, T^* T x\rangle$.  Thus $T^* T$ is the operator that represents the quadratic form $\|T x\|^2$.

Comment: A simple smaller example that might help is if $T$ is a complex vector then this is just the standard dot product.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's a very good point! Could you please elaborate on why this property is the most important one?

Comment: I think what you are seeing the SVD: the eigendecomposition of $T^* T$ tells you the right singular vectors and singular values of $T$, while the eigendecomposition of $T T^*$ tells you the left singular vectors and singular values of $T$.

Comment: For an engineer, what you refer is the so-called Gramian Matrix. In signal processing, this often roughly equals the co-variance matrix which measures the inner-product between the signal vectors (columns of $T$). $\rho(A*A)$ corresponds to the largest possible scaling $A$ can impart on a unit-norm vector. In principal component analyis, Eigenvectors of the Gramian plays the role of the principal components.

Comment: Surjectivity of $I+T^*T$ can be derived from Minty's theorem, since $T^*T$ is always a maximally monotone operator. By monotone, I mean $\langle T^*Tx | x \rangle \geq 0$. For my studies, I view $T^*T$ as a (usually easily accessible) operator that lets you do stuff with $T$ algorithmically. E.g. iterating $x_{n+1}=\|T\|^{-2} T^*Tx_n$, yields $x_n\to x\in \textrm{Fix} T^*T$. This operator is firmly nonexpansive and hence is easily used in combination with other nonlinear operators as well (e.g. in proximal gradient descent, douglas rachford algorithms, and product space variants thereof etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering it as an operator we have that its self adjont i.e $(T^{*}Tx,y)=(x,T^{*}Ty)$, and thus diagonalisable if its compact. One significant fact allowing this to happen is that the orthagonal complement of an eigenvector of the operator is invariant under the operator, atleast in Hilbert spaces. Hence once you prove that there is one eigenvector you inductively obtain a complete set of eigenvectors.

$I+T^{*}T$ has in the case when $T$ is compact index $0$ hence gives injectivity iff. surjectivity kind of resembling the fundamental theorem om linear algebra.

Comment: If $(I+T^*T)(v) = 0$, then $0 = \langle(I+T^*T)(v),v\rangle = |v|^2+|T(v)|^2$ implies $v = 0$, hence $I+T^*T$ is injective. Alternatively, diagonalize $T^*T$, then you also have a diagonalization of $I+T^*T$, and since the diagonal entries of $T^*T$ are nonnegative, the diagonal entries of $I+T^*T$ are positive. (This is for the finite dimensional case).

Comment: Surjectivity need not hold in the infinite dimensional case, for example if $T$ is left multiplication by $t$ on $\mathbb{R}[t]$, which is self-adjoint with respect to the inner product $\langle p,q\rangle = \int_0^1p(t)q(t)dt$. Then $I+T^*T = I+T^2$ is not surjective, because every nonzero element of its image has degree at least two.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie I dont think this is compact

Comment: Oh, right, I meant to put this as a separate answer.